# How can I stop `less` from removing ANSI color sequences from stdin?

Tags: less

```
tree go | less -R
```

Debian/Linux `tree` includes ANSI color escape sequences matching the form *ESC]...m* in its output.

I would like `less -R --RAW-CONTROL-CHARS` to output the incoming ANSI "color" sequences. I am wanting to see color in the output of less.

Instead, less says `There is no R-RAW-CONTROL-CHARS option ("less --help" for help)`

How can I stop `less` from removing ANSI color sequences from stdin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that it is not `less` that is removing the color sequences,
but rather `tree` that detects that its output is not to the console
and decides to omit the sequences.

The
[tree man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tree)
has this option which solves the problem for me:

> **-C**
>
> Turn colorization on always, using built-in color defaults if the
> LS_COLORS environment variable is not set. Useful to colorize output
> to a pipe.

Use it as follows :

```
tree -C | less -R
```

Comment: One problem down: tree -C | less -R does relay color, but less still produces the error "There is no R-RAW-CONTROL-CHARS option ("less --help" for help) Press RETURN to continue" which requires me to press return which is annoying.

Comment: Is `less` aliased with parameters?

Comment: I found the invalid --R-RAW-CONTROL-CHARS instead of --RAW-CONTROL-CHARS. Thank You.